# Fancybox2 modification to iframe with navigation buttons

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox-2

i have a list of iframe pop ups for which i am using the data-fancybox-group="gallery" so that the user can browser left and right through the content. The page this list sits in is also inside an iframe. the reason for this is so that the main header does not reload as it needs to play continuous music via soundcloud. I had to amend $('.fancybox').fancybox(); to make the iframe content automatically resize to fit the content and to appear outside it parent frame. However this amended script prevents the button function from working. this is my code, basically i need to get the iframe buttons function working like a gallery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        parent.$.fancybox({'href'          : this.href, 
        'type':'iframe',

        autoSize : false});
         //fancybox
        return false;
        }); //click

        /*$('.fancybox').fancybox();*/

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        parent.$('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


    });

</script>
```

Comment: Since you are calling fancybox in the manual mode (using `.click()`) the gallery has to be pushed in manual mode too. The buttons don't work because technically speaking you don't have a gallery. In other words, you have to push or group the elements of your gallery like `$.fancybox( [group], {// button options here})`. Check  my demo at http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_16Jan12.html (source code of iframe 2)

Comment: thanks JFK, your demo does exactly what i'm trying to do. i will try and get my head around this over the weekend. :)